# Can't see ruby process output in docker container with docker logs

Tags: ruby, docker

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ruby:2.4

CMD ruby -e "while true do; puts 'Hello, world!'; sleep 1; end"
```

When I run it `docker run <image>` I cannot see anything with `docker logs <container>`

Why? How to fix it?

P.S.

```
~$ docker --version
Docker version 18.03.1-ce, build 9ee9f40
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your docker run command?
you must use -d option in run command, not use -it

Comment: I did not use -it. It doesn't depend use I `-d` option or not `docker exec <container> ps` shows `?` for ttys and I see nothing when run `docker logs <container>`. Don't work

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are defining [CMD in the shell form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)

You should switch to exec form: ["executable","param1","param2"] if you don't want your command to be executed within shell

The result would be:

```
CMD ["ruby", "-e", "while true do; puts 'Hello, world!'; sleep 1; end"]
```

Comment: Nope, the same result.